# Sklearn models return weights of zero on small dataset

Tags: scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm currently trying to use sklearn to correlate population stagnation and happiness internationally. I've prepared and cleaned datasets with pandas, but for some reason, any model I try will not train. One of my columns for the data was countries, so I used pandas get_dummies function to account for feeding strings into the models. My shapes for the training and testing variables are as follows: (617, 67),(617,),(151, 67),(151,).

```
rf_class = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=5)
log_class = LogisticRegression()
svm_class = SVC(kernel='rbf', C=1E11, verbose=False)

def run(model, model_name='this model', trainX=trainX, trainY=trainY, testX=testX, testY=testY):
    # print(cross_val_score(model, trainX, trainY, scoring='accuracy', cv=10))
    accuracy = cross_val_score(model, trainX, trainY,
                               scoring='accuracy', cv=2).mean() * 100
    model.fit(trainX, trainY)
    testAccuracy = model.score(testX, testY)
    print("Training accuracy of "+model_name+" is: ", accuracy)
    print("Testing accuracy of "+model_name+" is: ", testAccuracy*100)
    print('\n')

# run(rf_class,'log')


model = log_class
model.fit(trainX,trainY)

perm = PermutationImportance(model, random_state=1).fit(testX, testY)
eli5.show_weights(perm, feature_names=feature_names)
```

Is my dataset simply too small to train on? Are the dummies too much for the models? Any help that can be offered is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your data is small, but it depends on you how you extract useful information from it. You didn't showed that out of 67 features, how many of were generated using dummies. You can merge few string in the column which was used to generate dummies based on some common criteria of some string cleaning/preprocessing.

Comment: also being more clear about what you mean by "will not train" would be helpful.

Comment: How many categories does `trainY` have?